# Add HTML5 WebGL game into Moodle LMS

Tags: html, moodle, scorm

i have been searching for this and found that this can be done by wrapping HTML5 game into scorm wrapper. but i can't find working library to do this or there are some but not working already tried
so anyone know the other way to add HTML5 game to moodle LMS

Thanks in Advance and sorry for my bad english:)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few libraries for supporting scorm.  I have a lot of info on the Wiki at this github site https://github.com/cybercussion/SCOBot

There are other libraries out there as well.  Remember SCORM has 2 basic items.  Communication, Packaging with SCORM 1.2.
So just dropping in the JavaScript will still require the packaging portion to add the zip to Moodle.

GL